# Are bahaism and babism counted as one of the branches of shiism?

Tags: shiism, sects

bahai or babi sects formed in an Islamic country (Iran).they follow Bahá’u’lláh and Ali mohammad shirazi or bab as their leader . Are they counted as branches of shiism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The sect of Bahaism is a sect of Babism sect. actually this is a sect which has its own beliefs. As far as I know, it is not counted as a real branch of Shiism.** To see the complete text regarding Bahaism and Babism you can see the site below. (note: I found the valid site below which consists of the mentioned matter in Arabic, Urdu, and Farsi, I hope it could be helpful and profitable for you (if you know one of the mentioned languages)

- [Arabic](http://islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa1483)
- [Urdu](http://islamquest.net/ur/archive/question/fa1483)
- [Persian (Farsi)](http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa1483)
- ([and http://montazeran.ir](http://montazeran.ir/makatebe-enherafi/bahaeeyat/154-1387-12-19-19-06-27.html))

---

**On the other hand, (briefly speaking),** **colonizing countries had a strong effects on supporting and survival and even the appearance of Bahaism.**

To see more matter regarding the issue  above and also concerning the appearance of them, refer to the links below.

- [bankmaghaleh.blogfa.com](http://bankmaghaleh.blogfa.com/post-11.aspx)
- [www.bahairesearch.org](http://www.bahairesearch.org/en/node/3313)
- [www.bahairesearch.org](http://www.bahairesearch.org/en/content/establishment)

Answer (score 5):

The Bahai Faith is clearly a religion, not a sect or school of thought within Islam. This is what the Bahais themselves say, and is generally recognized by objective sources such as books on comparative religions and in the statistics of the *World Christian Encyclopedia* (which is about all religions, not just Christianity) and adherents.com. Recently the Minister of religious affairs in Indonesia was asked this question, by another government department, and he replied that the Bahais are not a "current" (school of thought) in any other religion, they are a religious community in their own right. See

https://sensday.wordpress.com/2014/09/19/indonesias-religious-affairs-minister-clarifies-his-stance-on-recognizing-the-bahai-faith/ (or the short URL :
 http://wp.me/pNMoJ-27p)